# Aligning left right using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a code like this more or less

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="c1">
   <div>
   <div class="c2">
   <div>
   <div class="c3">
   <div>
   <div class="c4">
   <div>
</div>
```

By using flex, can I do this?

```
<c1>         <c3>
<c2>         <c4>
```

I know I can use `<ul>` or `<table>`, but I am just wondering if I can do it using flex. I have tried using flex but cannot accomplish it.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you were going for? I can't quite tell. https://jsfiddle.net/Lk46ffo4/ It's a modified version of W3 School's Flexbox example at https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap

Comment: content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 50px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

Comment: You can use `flex-direction:column` but it will required **fixed** height on the container to enable the wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/jonnowitts/pen/MGbogq)

Yes, this is possible with Flexbox - Set a height on the .content and the child divs (e.g. content: 100px, divs 50px) and specify `flex-flow: column wrap`

```
.content {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   align-content: stretch;
   height: 100px;
}

.content div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

`Flex-flow` is shorthand for `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap`.

`Flex-direction` sets the direction - row, column, row-reverse, column-reverse.

`Flex-wrap` wraps the flexible items (or not). By default this is `nowrap`, the demo uses `wrap` and you can also use `wrap-reverse`

Comment: I had the same answer but when .content div are inside a loop (if we don 't know how many loop) it won't work

Comment: True, could specify percentage heights on the child divs, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by modifying your markup to the following structure:

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="left-col">
       <div class="c1"><div>
       <div class="c2"><div>
   </div>
   <div class="right-col">
       <div class="c3"><div>
       <div class="c4"><div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now you have two columns. Simply add the following styles to your `CSS`:

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; // or whatever you want
    flex-direction: row; // row is the default value, so you don't need to specify it. It will place the cols beside each other.
}

.left-col, .right-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

By specifying `flex-direction: column;` the elements will be positioned below each other.

Here's some great resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Maybe you also want to check out the new native `grid-layout`: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with CSS grid, this is in my opinion more useful to use but this is the code that uses CSS grid

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="c1">test 1</div>
    <div class="c2">test 2</div>
    <div class="c3">test 3</div>
    <div class="c4">test 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: I think it will make : <c1> <c2> and next row <c3> <c4>. This is not what he wants

Answer (score 0):

And what about this trick ?

```css
.content
{ 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column; 
    height: 50px; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="c1">1</div>
    <div class="c2">2</div>
    <div class="c3">3</div>
    <div class="c4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do please consider below code.
**HTML**

```
 <div class="content ">  
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
       <div class="c1 col-6 text-center">c1
       </div>
       <div class="c2 col-6 text-center">c2
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
       <div class="c3 col-6 text-center">c3
       </div>
       <div class="c4 col-6 text-center">c4
       </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.justify-content-around {
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute!important;
    justify-content: space-around!important;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box!important;
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: flex!important;
}
```